# My service worker is not connecting to my content script in my Chrome extension. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, web-extension

I have been working on porting this manifest v2 Chrome extension to manifest V3 and while I did port the extension through changing the structure in the manifest file and replacing the `background.js` with `service-worker.js`. The structure of the directory of the Chrome extension seems acceptable and **should** work in manifest v3, but I have a persistent problem that I cannot get around. I get an error message that states…

> "Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."
>
> "Stack Trace"
>
> "service-worker.js:14 (anonymous function)"

Here is my `service-worker.js` code to put it into context. *Note: source code is licensed under the Mozilla Public License, version 2.*

```js
// Listen for the extension being reloaded or re-installed
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    // Query for all open tabs
    chrome.tabs.query({}, (tabs) => {
        tabs.forEach((tab) => {
            // Inject the content script into each open tab
            chrome.tabs.registerContentScripts(tab.id, {
                file: 'content-script.js'
            });
        });
    });
});

function sendAudioMessage(actionType, audioFile) {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, function(tabs) {
        tabs.forEach(async (tab) => {
            console.log(tab);
            if (tab.url.startsWith("chrome")) return false;
            try {
                await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
                    action: actionType
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
                console.trace();
            }
        });
    });
}

// *** Message Handler ***
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log(message, sender, sendResponse);
    switch (message.action) {
        case 'playNavigationSound':
            sendAudioMessage('playNavigationSound');
            break;
        case 'playDownloadCompleteSound':
            sendAudioMessage('playDownloadCompleteSound');
            break;
        case 'playDownloadErrorSound':
            sendAudioMessage('playDownloadErrorSound');
            break;
        case 'playMuteWarningSound':
            sendAudioMessage('playMuteWarningSound');
            break;
        case 'changeVolume':
            changeVolume(0.75);
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Unknown message action:', message.action);
    }
});
```

Also, here is my `content-script.js` code for context.

```js
// Helper function to play audio
function playAudio(audioFile) {
    console.log(audioFile, chrome.runtime.getURL(audioFile));
    const audio = new Audio(chrome.runtime.getURL(audioFile));
    // Play the audio only when the EventListener for click is triggered
    audio.addEventListener('click', () => {
        audio.play();
    });
  }
  
  // Helper function for setting volume
  function setAudioVolume(volumeLevel) {
    const audioElements = document.querySelectorAll('audio');
    audioElements.forEach(audio => {
      audio.volume = volumeLevel;
    });
  }
  
  // Receive messages from your service worker
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log(message, sender, sendResponse);
    switch (message.action) {
      case 'playNavigationSound':
        playAudio('nav.ogg');
        break;
      case 'playDownloadCompleteSound':
        playAudio('complete.ogg');
        break;
      case 'playDownloadErrorSound':
        playAudio('error.ogg');
        break;
      case 'playMuteWarningSound':
        playAudio('unlock.ogg');
        break;
      case 'changeVolume':
        setAudioVolume(message.volume);
        break;
      default:
        console.log('Unknown message action:', message.action);
    }
  });
```

Lastly, here is my `manifest.json` file.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "PopupSound",
  "description": "Plays a click sound when you click on a link. Also plays a trumpet sound when you finish downloading a file.",
  "author": "Michael Gunter",
  "version": "3.0",
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "default_locale": "en",
  "icons": {
    "46": "icon_46.png",
    "96": "icon_96.png",
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "background": {
      "service_worker": "service-worker.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
  }],
  "web_accessible_resources": [{
      "resources": [
          "*.ogg"
      ],
      "matches": [
          "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "extensions": []
  }],
  "permissions": [
      "webNavigation",
      "downloads",
      "tabs",
      "activeTab"
  ],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "content_security_policy": {}
}
```

I am so close to having the program work without any errors, but this issue is getting me stumped. I would greatly appreciate your help. Please and thank you.

I tried debugging with the Chrome DevTools, but I wasn't able to resolve my issue.

Comment: In Chrome you need to [re-inject content scripts](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension.

Comment: I tried to fix the issue by including the use of `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, but now I get a new error that states: `Error handling response: TypeError: chrome.tabs.executeScript is not a function at chrome-extension://gjmeggkaahhhklpkhmgffglpdaehodho/service-worker.js:7:21 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at chrome-extension://gjmeggkaahhhklpkhmgffglpdaehodho/service-worker.js:5:12`

Comment: Didn't this already get fixed?

Comment: Have you tried using `registerContentScripts()` instead of `execueScript()` to inject your content script? If I recollect correctly the `webNavigation` handlers were getting called before the content script was injected.

Comment: @MichaelGunter, use the example I've linked which shows how to use chrome.scripting.executeScript, which replaces chrome.tabs.executeScript in ManifestV3.

Comment: @guest271314, as the linked thread shows, the issue is that Chrome doesn't inject content scripts in the existing tabs after the extension is installed/updated/reloaded, which is intentional as stated by their programmers multiple times, so registerContentScripts won't help here.

Comment: @wOxxOm OP isn't using content scripts here, now. They are using `executeScript()`, which should work, after adjusting to `scripting.executeScript()` as you suggested. Looking again, I guess they are trying to use content scripts and inject the script with `executeScript()`. When I last worked with OP's code the issue was the `webNavigation` events were firing before the script was injected, thus no `onMessage` handler existsed at that time.

Comment: The OP is still using content scripts via content_scripts in manifest.json.

Comment: @guest271314, you're right about webNavigation timing though, so I guess we have two problems here. I would reverse the direction of communication and send a message from the content script that runs at document_start.

Comment: That should work, too. What I would do is inject an `iframe` into each Tab, then communicate using `postMessage()` with the `iframe`, where the `iframe` can communicate with the `ServiceWorker`, to avoid using `sendMessage` and `onMessage`. OP is already using `"web_accessible_resources"`.

Comment: What would using an `iframe` do, and how would it benefit me when running my extension?

Comment: Your current issue, at least per the code in the question and your description, is that you have a timing issue with message passing. Since you are already using `"web_accessible_resources"` you can create an `iframe` pointing to the extension URL, append that `iframe` to the `document`, then you can communicate with the `iframe` using `postMessage()`, and the `iframe` can communicate with the `ServiceWorker` using `postMessage()`. In theory that will get rid of your Chrome extention message passing issues.

Comment: @MichaelGunter See  https://github.com/guest271314/captureSystemAudio/blob/master/native_messaging/capture_system_audio/background_transferable.js#L112-L147, https://github.com/guest271314/captureSystemAudio/blob/master/native_messaging/capture_system_audio/transferableStream.js and https://github.com/guest271314/persistent-serviceworker/tree/main/chromium_extension_web_accessible_resources_iframe_message_event.

Comment: That is so confusing. I do not know how to approach that code. How do I get my Chrome extension working?

Comment: @MichaelGunter Did you get rid of `webNavigation` event handlers, or are they still in the actual code?

Comment: I got rid of “webNavigation” from my JavaScript code. When using CTRL+F (Find), the only instance of “webNavigation” in my project directory is my `manifest.json` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to establish message passing to all tabs where the URL does not beging with `"chrome"`.

We wait for a message from the content script before replying.

content-script.js

```
// Receive messages from your service worker
console.log("Content script");
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log(message);
});

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ url: location.href, title: document.title });
```

Here we reload all tabs that do not begin with `"chrome"` when we reload the extension.

service-worker.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(async (reason) => {
  console.log(reason);
  const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({});
  for (const tab of tabs) {
    if (tab.url.startsWith("chrome")) {
      continue;
    }
    await chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id);
  }
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  // console.log("onUpdated", tabId, changeInfo, tab);
});

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener((tab) => {
  // console.log("onCreated", tab);
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (message, sender) => {
  console.log(message);
  await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, "Message from ServiceWorker");
});
```

Comment: Thank you so far. That removes the service worker connection issue. Now, no audio is playing when I run the extension. Let me repeat, there are no more errors nor warnings, but now no audio plays when the user clicks links on a page.

Comment: You are going to have to deal with those `webNavigation` events. Or use an offscreen document to play audio.