# backhround.js doesn't accept messages from contentscript.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I can't send a message from contentscript to background.js, help
contentscript.js:

`chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ event: 'summarizingRequest'});`

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.event === 'summarizingRequest') {
      console.log('got it');
    }
});
```

I’ve already tried everything I know, it doesn’t work even in the most basic way, I don’t know what to do

Comment: Kindly include your manifest.json and the complete content script in the question body. Here's a working example of message passing from content script to MV3 `ServiceWorker` and back to the content script https://stackoverflow.com/a/78215332/.

Comment: I found an error in my manifest file. "world": "MAIN" in "content_scripts" breaks my program. But I can’t remove this either, I need access to the site’s global variable, which does not exist in the isolated world of the content script. Now I'm thinking about what the problem is. Thank you, you directed me to the right place

Comment: To send from the MAIN world you must either use [external messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/messaging#external-webpage) or use a second content script in the default world to relay the message via an intermediate CustomEvent, [example](/a/19312198).